# Why is my echo command writing two words over each other?

Tags: bash, carriage-return

I have a bash script which picks two words and (should) concatenate them.

```
#!/bin/bash

adj="$(shuf -n1 adjectives.txt)"
noun="$(shuf -n1 nouns.txt)"

echo ADJ $adj
echo NOU $noun

echo "$adj $noun"
```

The variables are being set correctly, but for some reason, the final echo doesn't work right. For instance:

```
ADJ humbler
NOU lyric
 lyricr
```

Or:

```
ADJ bipinnate
NOU lipases
 lipasese
```

What's happening here is that the final output is the adjective's last letter at the end of the noun. Why is this, and how can I stop it?

There is an Asciinema of this phenomenon here: https://asciinema.org/a/199297

Comment: Can you simplify the example by removing the randomness (e.g. write `adj=humbler` instead of `adj="$(shuf -n1 adjectives.txt)"`) and still reproduce the problem?

Comment: That doesn't break. So, must be DOS line endings in the file, I guess? That's annoying.

Comment: Are you using windows bash? It produces the result as expected on my Linux but not on windows bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input files most likely have CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings. The `\r` (carriage return) will cause the output to jump back to the first column of the current line, as your concatenation gets rid of the `\n` and not the `\r`.

That is the format used by Windows/DOS.

You can either convert the files, or you can strip it out using `tr`, e.g.:

```
adj="$(shuf -n1 adjectives.txt | tr -d '\r')"
noun="$(shuf -n1 nouns.txt | tr -d '\r')"
```

You can also run this across the files instead, e.g.:

```
tr -d '\r' < adjectives.txt > adjectives-reformatted.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, this is correct. I used the `dos2unix` utility to convert. I'll accept once SO lets me.